# How to send Stripe customer ID to Parse

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, stripe-payments

I've managed to create Stripe customers through Parse using this function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("customer", function(request, response){
stripe.customers.create({
    email: request.params.useremail
}, function(err, customer) {
    if(err){
            console.log(err);
            response.error(err);
    } 
    else{
            console.log(customer);
            response.success(customer);
    });
});
```

However, I would like to then be able to send the customer ID that is created to Parse under the current user's data as "cusToken", the same way that "email", "username" and whatnot are stored in the User class.

Comment: You can get the current user from the request.  Set the stripe id as a property on that user and save it.

Comment: Thank you. How do I go a bout this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two assumptions that will simplify this code, the first is that the client making the call always does so on behalf of it's logged-in user, not some other user.  The second is that stripe `create` answers a promise.  Assuming that:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("customer", function(request, response) {
    var user = request.user;
    stripeCreateP({ email: user.email }).then(function(customer) {
        user.set("someUserProperty", customer.someStripeProperty);  // as an example
        return user.save();
    }).then(function(result) {
        console.log(customer);
        response.success(customer); 
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        response.error(err);
    });
});
```

If the stripe api doesn't return a parse Promise, you can "promisify" it as follows...

```
function stripeCreateP(params) {
    var p = new Parse.Promise();
    stripe.customers.create(params, function(err, customer) {
        if (err) {
            p.resolve(customer);
        } else {
            p.reject(err);
        }
    });
    return p;
}
```

...and call that with the email param object...

```
stripeCreateP({ email: user.email }).then( ...
```

If your app calls this for a user other than the client's logged in user, then you will need to pass user email in `request.params` as you do in the OP, and furthermore, you'll need to give yourself permission in the code to save a user other than the current one, then you can precede the save with a `useMasterKey`.  See the docs for that.

Comment: Thank you very much! When using `var user = request.user()` I get the error:  **Property 'user' of object #<Object> is not a function**

Comment: @J.M, my bad.  It's not a function, it's a property `request.user`, no parens.  Edited.

Comment: Oh alright. That fixes it, however now there's a new error which is **Cannot call method 'then' of undefined at** `stripe.customers.create({ email: user.email }).then(function(customer)`

Comment: That means, as we worried, that the stripe create method doesn't have a promise returning version (something that responds to `then`).  So you'll need that promisified suggestion.

Comment: Alright. Now the then function works. I did `then(customer)`, and I get an unknown error. Is that what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: then is passed a function.  That function's first parameter is the result of the stripe call, which your code indicated is a customer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. So is `then(customer)` the right way to go about it? Once again, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you. I'm having an issue at `user.set("someUserProperty", customer.someStripeProperty);` So basically the Parse user property I'm using is "cusToken" (a string), and the Stripe property I'm trying to use is "customer.id". However, when I do `user.set("cusToken", customer.id);' I get an unknown error. You can find it here https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#customer_object

Comment: Your idea is right for setting the property on user.  Remember that the client must call this cloud code with a logged in user. If that's true, then I think you need to ask SO about the stripe API. A basic debugging step is to replace customer.id with a hardcoded string.

Comment: Hi @danh. Happy holidays. I just realized that the function is called twice, sometimes thrice. Would you by any chance know why and how to prevent it?

Comment: The only cause for something running twice is calling it twice. It's best to debug on the client side.